# Node.js node-serialport .on('data') missing data

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-serialport

I'm using node-serialport (version 2.0.6) on a Raspberry PI 2 running Ubuntu mate.  I have a usb to serial cable connected to a usb port of the RP as \dev\ttyUSB0.  I'm attempting to communicate with an old serial device with a protocol called PHP (Not the programming language).  The serial communication works perfectly when using minicom.

In minicom I can enter the string `;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B` followed by a carriage return and the device returns `'=CV65204E0000A30'`.  This is the correct response.

When I run the node.js program (version 4.3.1) I only get part of the data.  The part changes every time.  For example I will get `4E0000A` one time and `3D0` another time.  `3D0` is interesting because there should be no `D` in the return message.

```
/*jslint node : true, bitwise: true, esnext: true, vars: true, plusplus: true, devel: true, nomen: true, indent: 4, maxerr: 50, globalstrict: $
"use strict";

var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    databits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopbits: 1,
    flowcontrol: false
});


serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data);
    });

    var bytesToSend = ";402'\\PT\\GC1.FE02:CV'980B\r";
    console.log("sending:",bytesToSend);
    serialPort.write(bytesToSend, function(err, results) {
        serialPort.drain();
        if (err) {
            console.log('err ' + err);
        }
        console.log('results ' + results);
    });

});
```

Actual output below (should return `'=CV65204E0000A30'`)

```
tvann@tvann-pi2:~/node/serial$ node app
open
sending: ;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B
results 26
data received: 00A
^C
tvann@tvann-pi2:~/node/serial$ node app
open
sending: ;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B
results 26
data received: 65
data received: 0000A3
data received: D0
^C
tvann@tvann-pi2:~/node/serial$ node app
open
sending: ;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B
results 26
data received: A
data received: 3D0
^C
tvann@tvann-pi2:~/node/serial$ node app
open
sending: ;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B
results 26
data received: 4E
^C
tvann@tvann-pi2:~/node/serial$ node app
open
sending: ;402'\PT\GC1.FE02:CV'980B
results 26
data received: 4E0000A
```

I also have a variant of the program that sends the data in the form of a Uint8Array.  The results are exactly the same.